# Sending an array to Django via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to send a JavaScript array to Django via ajax, as follows.

`main.html`:

```
<a href=#>Click</a>

<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {

  var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('arr', arr);

  $.ajax({
    url: '...',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  });

});
</script>
```

And on the server side:

`views.py`:

```
@csrf_exempt
def main(request):
    arr = request.POST.get('arr')
    print(type(arr))
    print(arr)
    return render(request, 'main/main.html')
```

the result is a string: `'1,2,3,4'`.

If I retrieve the data with:

```
arr = request.POST.getlist('arr')
```

the result is a list containing a string: `['1,2,3,4']`

How can I get a real list like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved the problem: no `[]` in JavaScript data, but add `[]` in Python.

JS:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {'arr': arr},
});
```

Python:

```
arr = request.POST.get('arr[]')
```

And the result is a list with 4 elements: `['1', '2', '3', '4']`

Answer (score 11):

**Python 3+, Django 2+, jQuery**

*In your template*

```
data = {
      key_1_string: 'Value 1 is a string',
      key_2_array: ['1st Value of array', '2nd Value of array'],
      key_3_int: 1234,
      key_4_array_of_objects: JSON.stringify([{id: 3, name: "ABC"}, {id: 4, name: "CBA"}])
      ... rest of your keys/values you want to pass to Server
    }

$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'ajax_url' %}",
    method : "post",
    dataType : "json",
    data : data,
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function (response) {
        // Do some success scripts
        if (response.operation_status == 'ok') {
            alert ('All done ok')
        } else {
            alert ('Ups. Found some error!')
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        // Request error. Display right error message
        ...      
    });
```

*In your view*

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.http import JsonResponse

@require_POST
def ajax_view_for_ajax_url:
    string_value = request.POST.get('key_1_string')
    array_value = request.POST.getlist('key_2_array[]')
    int_value = request.POST.get('key_3_int')
    array_of_objects = json.loads(request.POST.get('key_4_array_of_objects'))
    
    # Do some magic code with all values
    return JsonResponse({
        'key_1':'value_1',
        'operation_status': 'ok or error',
        ... rest of your keys/values you want to pass to Client
    })
```

**If you don't like jQuery you can send like this**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "{% url 'ajax_url' %}", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", formData.csrfmiddlewaretoken);
xhr.onload = function () {
  // do something to response
  var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  if (json.operation_status == "ok") {
    alert ('All done ok');
  } else {
    alert ('Ups. Found some error!');
  }
};
xhr.send(postData);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send an array, you need to append elements a little bit different way:

```
formData.append('arr[]', arr);
```

Please check the documentation for more details and examples:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: The `[]` in `arr[]` is just PHP's naming convention. Django doesn't seem to respect that.

Comment: Well it is not only a PHP's naming convention, it is a way to send arrays as get parameters as part of URL in http protocol.

Comment: But the result of `arr = request.POST.get('arr[]')` is still a string: `'1,2,3,4'`, and `arr = request.POST.getlist('arr[]')` is still a list containing one string: `['1,2,3,4']`.

Comment: in django you have to get result without square brackets: `arr = request.POST.getlist('arr')`

Comment: Or if you work with post requests in django, then in ajax object you have to send `data: {'arr': [1, 2, 3, 4]}` without formData as mentioned in other answers. And then access this parameter in django normal way without square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use without formData.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  type: 'POST',
  data: arr,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
})
```

Comment: But `request.POST.get('arr')` will get nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to send the array like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {'arr', arr },
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
 })
```

Comment: I suppose it should be a semi-colon as `{'arr': arr}`. But Django still can not retrieve the array. The result is `None`.

Comment: send your data as json data , remove `processData: false` ,
 `contentType: false` and put `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 1):

the data that you send should be an object

for example

```
data = {
a : [1,2,3,4]
}
```

so

```
$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
})
```

Comment: I suppose it should be `arr: [1,2,3,4]`. But Django still can not retrieve the array. The result is None`.

Comment: what the response that you get ??

Comment: also content-type should be application/json

Comment: Changed to `contentType: 'application/json'` but `requset.POST.get('arr')` is still `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you need few things to take in account first of all you missing csrf_token 
without Django by default will drop any xhr request

now to normal Django view expect to forms and not to JSON so to get you desired result 
you code should look like that :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/test/',
    data: "{ 'a': [1,2,3,4] }",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded/json",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken":'{{ csrf_token }}'},
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result.d);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});

x-www-from-urlencoded - will threat data as form
```

with that code you data will be found in request.POST 
it you will set

```
content-type : 'application/json'
```

you will see the data in body of the request

the usage of set the CSRF Header , if you using you code in Django template 
you can use it that way 
if will not you will to parse cookie and set that that in ajax request

i hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

in **django** ,try something like this

 in your **js** file

```
key=['1','2','3'];
$.ajax({type:'GET',
url:'{% url "function_name " %}',
data:{'arr':key},
success:function(response){
 }
})
```

and in your **view.py** ,do something like this

```
key=request.GET.getlist('arr[]')
```